# Why method parameter and wildcard doesn't work interchangeably?

Tags: java, generics

I thought that parameter and wildcard placeholder roughly has same meaning, where the first one is for defining classes and methods and the second is for declaring variables. But apparently it is not the case.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Consumer<List<? extends Number>> l1 = null;
        Consumer<List<? extends Number>> l2 = null;

        l1 = l2;    // compiles
    }

    static <T extends Number> void m(Consumer<List<T>> l) {
        Consumer<List<? extends Number>> l3 = l; // doesn't compile
    }
}
```

I thought that line `Consumer<List<? extends Number>> l3 = l` should work just as `l1 = l2;`. But it is not the case. Can someone explain why this sample doesn't compile and how can I workaround this.

Comment: I would use `Consumer<List<T>> l2` though it's not obvious be me why this doesn't work.

Comment: The example is slightly artificial and therefore I cannot change the type of the `l3`. In my scenario it is a type of parameter of the other method.

Comment: You can use a raw type to get it to compile. :P

Comment: The issue is that Consumer<List<T>> l can be a list of anything however, Consumer<List<? extends Number>> l3 is much more specific.

Comment: @PeterLawrey you are right. This works: `Consumer<List<? extends Number>> l2 = (Consumer) l;` but is there some way to make it work without creating/suppressing a warning?

Comment: @ArtemPetrov this was a joke. [Don't use raw types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it).

Comment: You would think, alternatively an explanation of why this is dangerous in some way.

Comment: @JohnKane Method parameter T is just as strict as wildcard

Comment: @Turing85 I agree unless the compiler prevents you from writing sane code. ;)

Comment: `static <C extends Consumer<List<? extends Number>>> void m(C c) { C c3 = c; }` - would this be satisfactory?

Comment: `m(l1)` does not compile neither

Comment: Workaround: `Consumer<? extends List<? extends Number>> l3 = l;`

Comment: @Turing85 Type of 'l3' should not be changed. In real world scenario it is type of parameter of the other method.

Comment: @ArtemPetrov not even to `Consumer<List<? extends Number>>?`

Comment: Technically a dupe of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265 All the compiler sees is `Consumer<T1>` and `Consumer<T2>` where `T1 = List<T>` (e.g `List<Integer>`) and `T2 = List<? extends Number>`. Generics are invariant, so you can't assign one to the other.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat looks good for me

Comment: `Consumer<List<Number>>` does not match `Consumer<List<? extends Number>>`.  Wildcard matching is not recursive;  it only applies to the topmost level of a wildcard.

Comment: @Peter You can make it compile without using a raw type, if you go *via* a raw type with a "magic double cast" (don't know if it has an agreed name) `Consumer<List<? extends Number>> l3 = (Consumer<List<? extends Number>>)(Consumer)l; // compiles`

Comment: @Bohemian one cast is enough `Consumer<List<? extends Number>> l3 = (Consumer)l;`

Comment: @VGR Why `Consumer<List<T>> l` is treated as `Consumer<List<Number>>` and not as `Consumer<List<? extends Number>>`?

Comment: Because the compiler doesn’t know what T is, but the compiler does know that T must be a specific type.  T can never be a wildcard.

Comment: @Bohemian I have code with a magic triple cast ;)

Answer (score 0):

`Consumer<List<T>>` is not a subtype of `Consumer<List<? extends Number>>` even though `List<T>` is a subtype of `List<? extends Number>`, in the same way that `Foo<Dog>` is not a subtype of `Foo<Animal>` even though `Dog` is a subtype of `Animal`.

Generic type parameters are invariant, meaning that (unless you have a wildcard at the top level) they must match *exactly*. If you want it to be compatible with different type parameters, you must have a wildcard at the top level, like this:

```
Consumer<? extends List<? extends Number>> l3 = l;
```

Or you can just declare your method as

```
static void m(Consumer<? extends List<? extends Number>> l3)
```

and it will accept all the arguments that it accepted before.

(However, I want to point out that your method as declared with `Consumer` doesn't really make any sense. Your method is generic on `T`, and it takes in a consumer which takes in a `List<T>`. There is almost no way for your method to use this consumer, because your method would have to pass it a `List<T>`, but your method has no idea what `T` is, and it has no other arguments of type `T` or any other way to figure out what `T` is or get a `List<T>`, so the only thing it can safely pass in is an empty list. So the only way your method can use this consumer is to pass it an empty list, which is probably not very useful.)